# HashMap for storing big Cache

Tags: java, caching, hashmap

Consider there are some Objects that need to be reused number of times in a class. 
Individuall each Object can be large and the number of such Objects could be very large as well. A very simple exampleof such Objects could be Records in Database.

Storing such data in HAshMap instead of Querying again to Database after every 10 lines can help in performance. But, memory wise it is highly demanding .

How could HashMap contain lot of data but not keep all in memory at one. If it could give Objects on demand , it would be best ?

Comment: I think you'll have to manually handle it. [This may help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms).

Comment: Both of the answers you've had so far are taking the approach of simply limiting the size of the `HashMap`, so that anything which doesn't fit in is not kept in the map, and must be loaded from the database (or whatever) if needed. This is the usual way to do this. What you asked is, i think, whether the `HashMap` itself could be a two-level cache, keeping some entries in memory, and some elsewhere, say on disk. This is a different approach; perhaps future answers will address it.

Comment: YEah, let me explain the situation. I am doing simple ETL ( Extract fro database , transform and load to database) After extract and transforming large number of records, I keep them in HAshMap. And use HashMap to load int target database. So, this HashMap has 2 characteristics - First, it very quickly takes its full size , actually in first call itself and ther after, it is not changed for its lifecycle. SEcond, I can't have SoftREfernces because then it may be gC'd and since I don't have any more refernces, data is lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LRU based map for cache and where your length of the cache size is fixed where  `Least-Recently-Used` Objects will be remain in memory.

It is easy to get such map in java, `[LinkedHashMap][1]`.

```
final int MAX_ENTRIES = 100;
Map cache = new LinkedHashMap(MAX_ENTRIES+1, .75F, true) {
    // Returns true if this map should remove its eldest entry
    public boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
    }
};
```

You can also make your `Map` synchronized.

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(cache);
```

Comment: The Cache I am dealing with is some table level aggegations and whenever a HAshMap is called, all its entries are needed. And this cache has not be application wide visible. IT can be cleaned once the class in which declared is over. It is only a Table dump, But instead of goint to query table , idea was to check HashMap

Comment: If all entries are need you need to get it all in memory and which could be expensive.

Comment: I can drop the HashMaps and instead query databases repeatedly. I can get rid of HashMap after defering load to database ,but looks like there are just these 2 options

Comment: instead of that you can create a n sized lru map where you keep n numbers of data in case if any data not found in the map then search it in database and insert into map map will discard the not used value.
It will minimize the database call and also utilize memory efficiently.

In case if you need entire data then you bound to load all the data into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when implementing a cache that has the potential to be large, you want to use [SoftReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)s.  Typically it looks like this:

```
private final Map<KeyType, Reference<MyLargeObject>> cache =
    new HashMap<>();    // Or LinkedHashMap, as per Quoi's suggestion

public MyLargeObject getCachedValue(KeyType key) {
    Reference<MyLargeObject> ref = cache.get(key);
    return (ref != null ? ref.get() : null);
}

public void addToCache(KeyType key, MyLargeObject value) {
    cache.put(key, new SoftReference<MyLargeObject>(value));
}
```

A SoftReference holds an object but will allow that object to be garbage collected if memory becomes tight.  If the object does get garbage collected, SoftReference.get() returns null.